# Get last visible line's first char in RichTextBox using GetCharIndexFromPosition

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

So I have a rich text box and I am trying to get the index of the first char in the last visible line but I have an issue.

I am trying to retrieve the index by using:

```
int lastVisibleCharIndex= messageEditorRtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, messageEditorRtb.Height));
int lastVisibleLine= messageEditorRtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastVisibleCharIndex);
if (lastVisibleLine>= messageEditorRtb.Lines.Length) return;
```

Which works until the I try to retrieve the index of the last two lines in the rich text box. Whether the last visible line is the second last line or the last line, I always get the same lastVisibleCharIndex value and I don't know why that is. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to get the last visible line in a rich text box?

I included images of my issue to help explain it.

When running the code for the first image below return an index of 42.
[image]

When running the code for the next image below is also returning an index of 42.
[image]

The last line should return a index greater than the second last line. Can anyone see why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with new Point(0, messageEditorRtb.Height-1); ?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette I have, still gives me the same index. :(

Comment: Using the Height property is not correct, that includes the border.  If you'd use winforms then you'd use ClientSize.Height.  I can't guess what this is, always use the proper tag to tell us what GUI class library you use.

Comment: @HansPassant its Winforms my bad. But tried ClientSize.Height and still giving me the same index. Its a strange one...

Comment: @user3529319 I tried what Hans said. It works properly. Your height might be not enough to scrool between last and second last item.

Comment: @user3529319 Ok that could be it, I'll check

Comment: @user3529319 That was it, thanks